# Using jq to get a value, then using that value as a key to get another value

Tags: json, web-scraping, jq

I have several hundred taxonomic IDs, and I am using `curl` and `jq` to extract relevant values from http://taxonomy.jgi-psf.org/tax/accession.

Is there a way to pipe jq to itself so I can use the value of "level" as the key to another query?

For this example, I would like to combine these two commands into one:

```
$ curl -s http://taxonomy.jgi-psf.org/tax/tax_id/48479 | jq '.[] | .level'
```

**"no rank"**

```
$ curl -s http://taxonomy.jgi-psf.org/tax/tax_id/48479 | jq '.[] | ."no rank".name'
```

**"environmental samples"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `level` property value as a key:

```
$ curl -s http://taxonomy.jgi-psf.org/tax/tax_id/48479 | jq '.[] | .["\(.level)"].name'
"environmental samples"
```

Comment: You don't need string interpolation at all. `.[][.[].level].name` is enough.